# What is the best way to create page in Drupal 8 so that I can then add these posts with images?

Tags: php, drupal, content-management-system, drupal-8

I have a Home page on the Drupal website (such as is created after installation), but I still need to create this page:

[image]

What is the best way to create a page so that I can then add these posts with images?

I am just starting to learn Drupal and have heard so far about such ways of creating pages:
1) in admin toolbar: Content / Add Content / Article
2) in admin toolbar: Content / Add Content / Basic page
3) in admin toolbar: Structure / Views / Add Views

#### Which one should I use? Or maybe there is some other option that I don’t know about?

P.S. At the moment I am more interested how to create empty page on which I can then add posts later, and adding posts it is another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Drupal.

Drupal ships with the default theme which won't look nice but it does its job in the right way. Now if you want to create a better UI/UX obviously you should create a new theme. But before that make sure to read and understand the concepts behind Drupal. Drupal docs are your first friend.

[Drupal Documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs)

Drupal considers everything as nodes and that's how Drupal got its power. As you mentioned, Articles, Basic Page etc are called content types and they can be used to create a particular type of content.

Now for your purpose create a new content type and add the fields you need. From the image above I can say your content type needs Title, Image, Category and Date. After creating content type you can create as many contents as you want under the content type you just created. Consider each card in your image as content.

Now you can use a Drupal Core Module `Views`, to perform DataBase Operations without writing single code. Yes, you can select fields, sort, order etc with `Views UI` and display it in a page or a part of a page (Block).

I would say just try this out in the default Drupal theme and when you understand how this works, you can start creating your own theme for your project.

[Theming Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal)

There is a lot of resources available. But you have to make sure what you are asking is whether you actually need. It will take some time, but it worth.

Answer (score 0):

To build layouts for homepages on Drupal 8 you best friend is https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/layout-builder

To build the content blocks inside your home page, you should start creating nodes on a node content type to hold your information. For instance: news content type, with a title, a body, a date, and an image.

For every node type, ex. news, work on the preview display, full display, and any other display which makes sense. These displays can be used later in the Layout Builder directly or in Views, referenced below.

If you wish your list to be dynamic, such as the last 10 entries are shown first, then use a view to hold the content sorted and filtered as you need.

In a nutshell.

1. Create a content type for your article/news.
2. Modify the displays of the content types to have at least a summary and full view.
3. Create the content itself to have something to see.
4. Create the view (block) to filter and sort your content.
5. Create a page layout (this makes sense for landing pages) which places your new view and any other content you need in any disposition.

This is roughly what I would do. The steps described above contain many intermediate steps. If in doubt, check the docs.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. First, decide what will you display on that page. Is it content in some existing content type (article maybe) or you want to crate new one for this purpose.
2. If you need new one then create it (Structure -> Content types -> Add content type). 
   Then check what fields will you need. I.e. image, some description text. Add missing ones.
3. Create few nodes (pages) in that type so you could work with them.
4. Then for displaying you should crate a view (Structure -> Views -> Add view). It can be a page view (you are displaying only that content on page) or block view (this is just a block among some others). If you create a page you could visit it and if you create a block you have to add it to some region to appear on page (Structure -> Block Layout).
5. Inside your theme you should create templates for this page/block. Turn on twig debug mode so it will show you hints - what templates are used and how can you name yours to override default ones.
6. Adjust CSS to make it look like you want it to look.

Find some tutorial(s) for the details

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers have given the flow of the work you should go through, I would like to add some resource that might help you achieve this.

1. Creating content type and fields: https://www.drupal.org/docs/administering-a-drupal-site/managing-content-0/working-with-content-types-and-fields
   https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/structure-content-type.html
2. View and View modes: https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/views-concept.html
   https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api/display-modes-view-modes-and-form-modes
3. Handling block of the view: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/block/overview

Feel free to ask if any further explanation is needed. 
Thank you